# NSTableView select row by pressing "space"

Tags: cocoa, selection, nstableview

I didn't find any information on this question, and I wonder if it is possible to make NSTableView (or subclass) to select rows by pressing space bar on keyboard, and navigate through rows by pressing up/down keys without the selection being reset. I want to make nstableview to behave like total commander's file panel, if someone used it under windows. And I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make subclass of the NSTableView class. This is basic example how you could do it. It handles selection with the spacebar and with the right mouse button, hoever it does not handle right mouse button drag selection.

The idea is to use NSTableView in single select mode and implement alternative selection. We add property *markedRows* and then use it instead of original *selectedRows* property.

**FOTableView.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface FOTableView : NSTableView

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableIndexSet *markedRows;

@end
```

**FOTableView.m**

```
#import "FOTableView.h"

@implementation FOTableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }

    return self;
}

-(NSMutableIndexSet *) markedRows
{
    if (!_markedRows) {
        _markedRows = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    }
    return _markedRows;
}

- (void)drawRow:(NSInteger)row clipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
{
    if ([self.markedRows containsIndex:row]) {
        NSRect clipRect = [self rectOfRow:row];
        NSColor *color =  [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.932 green:0.046 blue:0.960 alpha:1.000];
        [color setFill];
        NSRectFill(clipRect);
    }

    [super drawRow:row clipRect:clipRect];
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *keyString;
    unichar  keyChar;

    keyString = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    keyChar = [keyString characterAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger row = [self selectedRow];
    switch(keyChar){            
        case 32:
        {
             if (row != -1)
             {
                 if ([self.markedRows containsIndex:row]) {
                     [self.markedRows removeIndex:row];
                 }
                 else {
                     [self.markedRows addIndex:row];
                 }
             }
            [self selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:++row] byExtendingSelection:NO];
            [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
            break;
        }

        default:
            [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }

    NSLog(@"key pressed: (%hu)%@", keyChar,keyString);
}

- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:[self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil]];
    if ([self.markedRows containsIndex:row]) {
        [self.markedRows removeIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        [self.markedRows addIndex:row];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Robert I use this solution to mark rows in a tableview, however I found a problem: If I sort the tableview by click the table headers, the tableview get sorted, but the "markedRows" index set did not get sorted, so it would store the wrong indexes of marked items, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @treblam Hm, you should store something unique from each item, maybe even pointer and then use that instead of the indexes.