# Is there an API to specify which items to be dragged in NSTableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I am implementing a drag&drop from a NSTableView to another NSTableView. The NSTableView's default drag behavior is like this: If the file under cursor is not selected in the tableview, then this one file is to be dragged, if the file under cursor is selected in the tableview, then all the selected files is to be dragged.  But in my APP, I need to specify which items to be dragged from the source tableview, is there an API for me to specify the items (not necessarily the selected ones) to be dragged?

Comment: `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableView` have methods with 'drag' in the name. What did you try?

Comment: @Willeke I've read all the APIs in the document, but can't find any API that can be used to specify the files to be dragged. It seems only the default behavior is allowed, either the file under cursor, or all the selected files can be dragged.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a try.

Comment: It looks like you have to override `mouseDown:`. If you could modify the dragged rows, the user would be confused.

Comment: I had made my NSTableView select row by pressing "space", the solution is been described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715826/nstableview-select-row-by-pressing-space/15044986#comment54105994_15044986), so actually I used markedRows instead of the built in selectedRows property, if a drag starts, I want to drag the markedRows instead of the selectedRows, this is why I want to be able to specify which rows to be dragged.